# Separating JQuery Scripts with Selectors in External file does not work?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a JQuery Selector and an event associates with it.I want to keep it in external file and just copy and directly save it. The thing which I see is that the external JavaScript that has the selector does not work. Can someone explain Why?

NOTE: I am able to use the same function within my HTML file but when externalize it. It just doesn't work .
The script that I have is as follows:-

```
 $('#pervious').click(function() {
        var presentSlide = $('.visible').attr('id');
        var tempArr = presentSlide.split("-");
        var persentSlideNo = tempArr[1];
        var perviousSlideNo = Number(persentSlideNo) - 1; if (perviousSlideNo > -1) 
        {
        var perviousSlide = "Slide-" + perviousSlideNo;

            $('#' + presentSlide).fadeOut('slow',function(){
            $(this).removeClass('visible').addClass('hidden');
            });
            $('#' + perviousSlide).fadeIn('slow',function(){
            $(this).removeClass('hidden').addClass('visible');
            });
        }

    });
```

Comment: the same script is I replace by `function perviousSlide()
{
 var presentSlide = $('.visible').attr('id');
        var tempArr = presentSlide.split("-");
        var persentSlideNo = tempArr[1];
        var perviousSlideNo = Number(persentSlideNo) - 1;
        //So that the last slide enters the if condition.
          /Some Code Here/
            
        }
}` gives me the correct thing with the onClick event. So can you tell me what is the problem with the above.

Comment: when you put `alert('hello');` at the beginning of the external script does it pop up? Is it being linked to correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How are you including this script?

Note that it needs to go below the definition of your `id=pervious` element, or it needs to go after it (e.g. `document.ready`), otherwise the element won't exist, and there won't be anything to bind to.

**UPDATE**
To restate, it needs to execute AFTER the `pervious` element gets created. Putting it in an external document is likely causing it to execute BEFORE the `pervious` HTML element is created, and therefore it doesn't work. You can put it in an external file, sure, just make certain that the element gets loaded, e.g.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getScript('http://yoursite.com/extrascript.js');
});
```

Comment: I have placed it into a single external javaScript. Outside the Document.Ready.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/shivkumarganesh/YTpJ2/39/  this is the example where I have put it into document.ready and it works fine. Can I get some document to understand this better

Comment: Formerly I wrote the things outside Document.Ready!! :( please let me know if any docs are there online so that I can refer?

Comment: @Shiv: Have a look at the official jQuery tutorials, especially http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:How_jQuery_Works, and of course there is http://api.jquery.com/ which describes all methods in more detail

Answer (score 2):

After you have determined you are actually linking to it by doing an alert, wrap your code like so:

```
$(function(){
    // place your code inside here for ready event
});
```

What you are doing is running your selector before the document is ready. The selector runs before the dom is there and there is no results in the selector so you don't attach anything.

Comment: also, "pervious" should be "previous" FYI because "pervious" sound like the tendency to be perverted :)

Answer (score 2):

You have to include scripts with the form of: (including the closure tag as such)

```
<script src="myexternal.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Not any of these:

```
<script src="myexternal.js" type="text/javascript" />
<script src="myexternal.js" />
<script src="myexternal.js" ></script>
```

form or it will not always get rendered properly and thus not execute.

and of course, since you are using jQuery, you should put YOUR code AFTER the jQuery library link AND include your code in a document ready as others have demonstrated.

Comment: Yes this is always the secret problem! THanks for this.